# Allow Azure Application Gateway to route all sub paths in AKS

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have AKS configured with Azure Application Gateway as my ingress.

I am trying to deploy a .net core Angular app to a path within the cluster. I would like to access the app on `http://<cluster ip>/app1`.

My kubernetes deployment (including ingress settings) is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web-app-1
  labels:
    app: web-app-1
spec:
  containers:
  - image: "xxx.azurecr.io/web-app-1:latest"
    name: web-app-1
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      protocol: TCP

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-app-1
spec:
  selector:
    app: web-app-1
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-app-1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: web-app-1
          servicePort: 80
```

In the Angular app itself, I have left `<base href="/" />` in `index.html`. However, I have amended the build to now be `ng build --base-href /app1/"`

---

## Issue

When this is deployed and I browse to `http://<cluster ip>/app1` then it loads the index.html file. However it returns a 404 for all the additional scripts e.g. 404 on `http://<cluster ip>/app1/main-es2015.9ae13a2658e759db61f5.js`

The issue could be with how I've configured Angular, but browsing to `http://<cluster ip>/app1/index.html` returns a 404 when I know it can be accessed just using `/app1/`.

I believe the issue is that Application Gateway is not routing requests properly for anything after `/app1/`. How can I get it to allow sub routes through (i.e. the scripts)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working now. If I looked at the 404 response headers it says it was from kestrel, so was hitting the dotnet core api, so it needs configuring there. All the changes I made were:

Client:

- Leave the base href as `/` e.g.
- Add the base href to the build argument e.g. ng build --base-href /app1/"
- In `Configure` of `Startup.cs`, add `app.UsePathBase("/app1");` I do this in the `else` of `env.IsDevelopment()`.

Application Gateway:

- Change the path for the rules to `- path: /app1*`. I didn't have the asterisk so wasn't routing all subsequent routes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: appgw-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/*
    ....
```

Where you are updating the routing prefix form "/" to "/api/*" . Specifically this annotation

```
appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
```